# Google Cloud Scheduler Run at Set Times Every Minute

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to call an api every minute for ski lift status and check for changes.  I am going to store the value of if the lift is open or closed in firebase (Real Time Database) and read to see if value from api is different and only update/ write to that node when it's a different value.  Then I can set up a cloud function that will listen for database changes and send push notifications to the list of FCM tokens from that channel.  I am not sure if this is the most efficient way, but I was going to set up scheduled functions to call the third party api.

I have been using these docs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

I was planning to do something like this:

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun((context) => {
  CALL MY API IN HERE AND UPDATE DATABASE IF SNAPSHOT BACK IS DIFFERENT
});
```

I was wondering how would I run only between set times- say 8am-6pm EST.  I am struggling to find anything about times to run.  Should I just run the function every minute and then pause and resume by checking the time?  In which case how does it know to keep checking the time when it is paused?

Comment: Did you try `'every 5 minutes from 08:00 to 18:00'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase scheduled functions use Cloud Scheduler to implement the schedule.  It accepts [cron style time specifiers](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/configuring/cron-job-schedules) to indicate when a job should be run.  The full spec for that can be found [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html).  You will have to use ranges of numbers to indicate the valid times and frequency of the schedule.  For example, you might use "8-18" in the hour field to limit the hours of execution.